# C# - Get value based on key from dynamic list

Tags: c#, list

I have a dynamic list(docs) which is looped as follows and

```
var docs = {{"with Space": "2",  "withoutSpace": "5", }}

  var a = docs[0].withoutSpace; // Working
  var b = docs[0].with Space; // Not working
```

How to get values from keys having space in c# list. docs I have mentioned here is a static list. But In my coding I have  dynamic list

Comment: Are your sure, you're able to access it `docs[i].withoutSpace`  because  `var docs = [ {"withoutSpace": 5, "with Space": 3}, {"withoutSpace": 7, "with Space": 9} ]`   will give `ERROR`

Comment: That first line isn't C# - what is it?

Comment: It seems to be JS

Comment: You can't create variable with keys having space.

Comment: Modified my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
dynamic docs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("[{\"with Space\": \"2\",  \"withoutSpace\": \"5\" }]");

Console.WriteLine(docs[0].withoutSpace); // "5"
Console.WriteLine(docs[0]["withoutSpace"]); // "5"
Console.WriteLine(docs[0]["with Space"]); // "2"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Reflection as follows

```
docs[i].GetType().GetProperty("with Space").GetValue(docs[i], null);
```

Comment: I already tried this. It throws the following error Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference